# Does there exist any uniformly continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(n)>n^2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to find an answer to the question that does there exist any uniformly continuous function on positive reals such that $f(n)>n^2$ holds for every n natural?I found this problem as a result in an analysis book.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Every uniformly continuous function satisfies an inequality of the type $f(x) \leq ax+b$ for some constants $a$ and $ b$.

Details: there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| <1$ if $|x-y| \leq \delta$. Now consider a partition of $[n,n+1]$ by intervals of length at most $\delta$. The number of intervals you need does not exceed $[\frac 1 {\delta}]+1$. Call  this $N$. Then $|f(n+1)-f(n)| \leq N$ by triangle inequlity. Hence $f(n+1) <N+f(n)$. By iteration this gives $f(n) <nN+f(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the definition of uniform continuity :
\begin{equation*}
(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\,\eta>0)(\forall(x,y)\in{\mathbb R^+}^2) ((\left|y-x\right|<\eta)\Longrightarrow (\left|f(y)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon))
\end{equation*}
Could you apply this to $\epsilon=2$ ?